# Color Picker with "no color" option?

Tags: matrix, fieldtypes

I want let the editor to choose an optional color via the color picker, but this didn't have the option 'no color' (or transparent).

Is there a solution to this? I use it a lot and have always to add a boolean switch so the editor can switch it on and off, but that's not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is no better solution for this. You could write a plugin that defines a new fieldtype.

Comment: There are now a couple of plugins - Spectrum mentioned below, and [Hue](https://github.com/TopShelfCraft/Hue)

Answer (score 0):

I just put together a fieldtype using the jQuery colour picker [Spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/)

[image]

It supports selecting no color and outputs a HEX of the colour, if chosen :)

[Get the fieldtype on Github](https://github.com/alecritson/craft-spectrum-fieldtype)